# SQL Date Format from UNIX string and then Like Select

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I am attempting to try and query a SQL Database which stores dates as strings, in the UNIX format, ddd MM  d or ddd MM dd. I am having trouble converting these to any sort of SQL Date format so that I can do a query using Like on the Date field so I can find the closest date to the requested one.

For an overview of what I am doing, I have a aspx page that has 2 date pickers on it. The user selects a start and end date, that is converted into the same format as used in the database (ddd MM  d or ddd MM dd) I then use a MIN/MAX select to find the lowest matching ID and highest matching ID to the dates supplied. That works fine, IF that date passed in has records. However, I want to convert the date stored in the database to a format where I can do a select first date after the passed in date, and the last date before the end passed date so I can return all of the rows in between. To achieve that I need to get the date into a format I can work with in SQL rather than just a nvarchar as its stored now.

What do you recommend (other than the obvious, of storing the dates as proper dates in the first place which is out of my control) as the easiest way of achieving what I am after

```
|  ID  |  Date         | Notes                 | 
| 1000 |Fri Mar  2     | Something Interesting |
| 1001 |Mon Mar  5     | Something Good        |
| 1002 |Fri Mar  9     | Something Good        |
| 1003 |Mon Mar 12     | Something Interesting |
```

I am passing in Sun Mar  4 as a start date and Fri Mar  9 as an end date. I however want to get all records between those days. currently my code is:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReport] 
    @StartDate nvarchar(50), 
    @EndDate nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @startID int
    DECLARE @endID int

    SELECT @StartID = MIN(ID)  FROM [HistoricalStatus]
    WHERE timeconnected LIKE @StartDate + '%'

    SELECT @endID = MAX(ID) FROM HistoricalStatus
    WHERE timeconnected LIKE @EndDate + '%'

    SELECT TOP 1000 *
      FROM [HistoricalStatus]
      WHERE ID BETWEEN @startID AND @endID
      ORDER BY id ASC
END
```

However, as you can see that will only ever work for dates passed in that actually have values in the Database. I want to find a way to select everything between the dates passed in whether or not they exist in the first place. My only guess is I have to convert the date column into proper date format then I can do things with the LIKE operator to get dates closest to the ones being requested?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking to convert a string to a date,

The following assumes current year

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Date] varchar(50),[Notes] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1000,'Fri Mar  2','Something Interesting')
,(1001,'Mon Mar  5','Something Good')
,(1002,'Fri Mar  9','Something Good')
,(1003,'Mon Mar 12','Something Interesting')

Select * 
      ,AsDate = try_convert(date,substring([Date],4,25)+' '+datename(year,getdate()))
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID      Date        Notes                   AsDate
1000    Fri Mar  2  Something Interesting   2018-03-02
1001    Mon Mar  5  Something Good          2018-03-05
1002    Fri Mar  9  Something Good          2018-03-09
1003    Mon Mar 12  Something Interesting   2018-03-12
```

Comment: Thanks @John Cappelletti, I'm new to SQL and didnt even know this was possible, let alone so simple. Drawing this out into a temp table filtering based on the AsDate column was so simple after the simple date conversion!

Comment: @LordBoBCUP Happy to help